# What's the most efficient / most precise way to track time in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, ipad

I know there is:

```
NSTimeInterval timestamp = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
```

but there is also:

```
CFTimeInterval timestamp = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
```

Is one faster / more efficient / more precise than the other?

Comment: Without testing, I would suspect that the NSDate method simply invokes CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent, hence will be _slightly_ less efficient.

Comment: ..but how about trying it yourself. You got all the tools at hand - use instruments!

Answer (score 0):

how about `mach_absolute_time`? Don't think you can get more precise than that